# Stored variable from web service in VBA for Excel 2013

Tags: vba, web-services, excel

I use a webservice function to get commodity prices in an Excel spreadsheet.  I have VBA code that references the values of the cells in which these prices are stored.  I would like to be able to get this value stored in my macro without having to use the function in a cell.  An example of my webservice function:

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CLF16.nym&f=l1")
```

My macro takes the current month and year to build the URL (the ticker codes for futures vary by date, so `CLF16.nym` is crude oil price for January 2016).

Is it possible to get this commodity price as a value in VBA without using the webservice function?

Comment: Do you simply want to avoid using functions directly on the worksheet, or is there something about this particular function you want to avoid?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using functions directly on the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to avoid using the function on the sheet, you can use the very same worksheet formula directly in code by using the `WorksheetFunction` property of `Application`, e.g.:

```
Dim s As String
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.WebService("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CLF16.nym&f=l1")
```

Comment: Simple enough.  When starting out in VBA I always had problems using worksheet functions in VBA and abandoned that technique.  Seems to work fine though!